# onMapReady method not applying to Google Maps Display

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, api-key

I am looking to display a Google Maps Display on a fragment layout within android studio. I have already downloaded Google play services in the SDK and have made the appropriate changes to my gradle files (I Think). I have made some changes to the android manifest file as well to grant user permissions etc. At run time a google maps display renders but the lng and lat are set to 0 so when the map displays, it shows me an area around Africa. I have made methods in the java file such as onMapReady, which is supposed to display the map at a different location and have it more zoomed in. The onMapReady function calls another method called goToLocationZoom, which holds the required functionality to allow the map to move to this location but for some reason everytime I run it, it always stays to the area around Africa, even though I have changed the lng and lat values. I am following a tutorial to achieve this, and in there Activty_home.XML file, they have their layout to linear, whilst mine is set to constraint but I don't think this would cause the issue. Does anyone know how to display the map to the lng and lat values that I have specified in the java file?

Below is my Java file code:

```
com.example.cmpkbest.lifestylefitnessapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

public class ViewLifestyles extends AppCompatActivity implements 

    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_lifestyles);
        initMap();
    }

    private void initMap () {
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager ().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        goToLocationZoom (53.408743, -2.984154, 15);
    }

    private void goToLocation (double lat, double lng) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll);
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

    private void goToLocationZoom (double lat, double lng, float zoom) {
        LatLng ll = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);
    }

}
```

Below is my Manifest code:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.cmpkbest.lifestylefitnessapp">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

        <permission android:name="com.example.cmpkbest.lifestylefitnessapp.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"
                    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.cmpkbest.lifestylefitnessapp.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permissions.READ_GSERVICES" />

        <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />


        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity android:name=".RegistrationPage">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".Login" />
            <activity android:name=".Home" />
            <activity android:name=".ViewLifestyles" />
            <activity android:name=".Workouts" />
            <activity android:name=".Notemaker"></activity>

            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="AIzaSyAkAQlA2B8_E5pPNH_jdAWSJpf915uozi8 " />

            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Below is my Gradle Files:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.cmpkbest.lifestylefitnessapp"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:+'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
}
```

Finally, my Layout.XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg5"
    tools:context="com.example.cmpkbest.lifestylefitnessapp.ViewLifestyles"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="346dp"
        android:layout_height="212dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.084" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Use this demo activity link to show using 'getSupportFragmentManager' which is intended for use with the AppCompatActivity: https://github.com/codepath/android-google-maps-demo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/MapDemoActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

I also had a project doing same output. I handle it this way.

So first you have to initialize the map

```
if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (mMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
}
```

Then i call setUpMap right after initializing it, not relying on onMapReady

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
            lastLocation.getLatitude(), lastLocation.getLongitude()), 15));

mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
mMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

Hope this helps